# Screen capture program with trim function

Tags: windows-xp, screen-capture

I need a simple, no nonsense nor bloatware screen capture program with the ability to
- capture the current application
- capture full screen
- save the files with increasing index in the filename into a predefined directory for quick capturing
- and a trim function

I'm making some tutorials for some students, and most of the ones I've seen fail on at least one of those requirements.

Has anyone got any recommendations perhaps?

*This is not a -mention every screen capture program in existence- question.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org), it fit all your needs with the following exception

- When you use auto-saving, you can't edit (trim for example) the screenshot before it's saved.
- The current version (3.1.5) is a little bit heavy (> 10 MB), the old versions are lightweight (ver 2.1.5 < 1.5 MB)